# Regex pattern "^\\|:\\|$" not detecting pipes at beginning and end of string

Tags: java, regex

The following piece of code returns false when I believe it should return true. Can anyone tell me why?
It's using java.util.regex.Pattern to parse the regex.

```
Pattern.compile("^\|:\|$".matcher("|   |").matches();
```

Comment: "design patterns " is absolutely not "regex patterns"

Comment: The point is that `matches()` requires a full string match.

Comment: Why the : and the space ? I don't get the logic of this attempt. Did you want `"^\\|.*\\|$"` ?

Comment: It should return false, it can only match the string `|:|`.

Comment: I'm trying to detect strings that begin with '|', end with '|' and can have anything or nothing in between.

Answer (score 2):

A `\` in a string literal must be escaped as `\\`.

If you want to match anything in between, use `.*`, not `:`.

When you use the [`matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) method in Java, you don't need to add the string boundaries `^` and `$` as this function returns `true` only when it matches the whole string.

You seem to want

```
Pattern.compile("\\|.*\\|").matcher("| |").matches();
```

Comment: I think you mean `"\\|.*\\|"`

Comment: @revo yes, thanks (took me a while to see the difference... this string escaping is so painful...)

Comment: Note that I didn't delete this answer (for now) as I'm still unsure whether it's useful or not (the question is clearly not an exact duplicate IMO)

Comment: Also I think first line of answer is not necessary anymore. Upvoted.